# Comma Trends Questions

Tags: punctuation

I’ve heard it’s becoming more acceptable to omit commas if doing so doesn’t make the writing confusing.

If a sentence starts with a subordinate / dependent clause but the sentence is short, does it need the comma? For example:

`When spring arrives, the flowers bloom.`

Can the comma be omitted?

Comment: short answer: short sentences...yes.

Comment: 1. Please finish reading the [tour] to find out how this site works. 2. Please use appropriate tags — punctuation is not grammar. 3. Tell us what you think the answer to your question is. What do you think the purpose of punctuation is?  Does what you suggest help or hinder that purpose? Or is your question an expression of a hope that someone here will say that you can ignore punctuation so you don’t have to think about what you are writing?

Comment: A slightly longer short answer: Speak the sentence out loud. If you feel the need for a breath (i.e. for emphasis), put the comma. Good writing should have "flow".

Comment: The one comma rule I learned in school was: "If in doubt, leave it out". I'm but not sure if teacher wrote the rule with or without comma ...

Comment: Hasn't "omit commas if doing so doesn’t make the writing confusing" always been acceptable? Sometimes adding or removing commas can change the meaning, so obviously don't omit those commas, but sometimes they're just about how you want the sentence to flow, so for those it's just a matter of personal preference.